# hos to post form to method in to an action in webpart

Tags: web-part

I have a html form it should be post content to action("searchUser") in backend

user.ascx:

```
<form action="/searchUser" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
...
</form>
```

user.ascx.cs:

```
public void searchUser(QueryModel params)
{
    ...
}
```

logic is very basic but couldnt resolve it..